# selected spinner value is updated in mysql db via soap webservice in android

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, android-spinner, insert-update

hi i got the solution for selected spinner item is inserted in mysql database through calling soap webservice..thanks for giving nice ideas.but i can't develop update spinner value is save in mysql database.please refer my code:[android code](http://pastie.org/4578986)

[webservice code](http://pastie.org/4578991)
...the above both link for inserting code for both android and webservices....please help me...what line is change for update spinner value also change in mysql database....

```
     public class update {

 public String insertData(String status,String username){

  try{

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/androidlogin","root","");
   PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("UPDATE `user` set `status` = 'C'  where `status` = 'Q'");
   int result = statement.executeUpdate();
  }

   catch(Exception exc){
    System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

  return "Updation successfull!!";
  }

}
```

please help me how is wrote android code for this update function...