# update data using java code in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, propertyinfo

if i have to insert the data in mysql database means we are use below code:

```
PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
unameProp.setValue(selectedItem);//Define value for fname variable
unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
request.addProperty(unameProp);
```

here the addproperty is used....how is wrote the code for update the data in mysql database in android...please help me...

Comment: Android doesn't support mysql. Do you mean server side?

Comment: MySQL in android is not the easiest way to go about this ...

Comment: ya i know...i have to call soap webservice here

Comment: please refer this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104500/selected-spinner-value-is-updated-in-mysql-db-via-soap-webservice-in-android..and give me solution

Answer (score 0):

android supports sqlite

you will have to use content values for db insertion in android

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put("userName", selectedItem); 



     db.insert(yrtbl, null, values);
     db.close();
```